# How do I iterate over a string in specific intervals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write this code to count the number of 'bob' s in a given string.This is why I want to be able to scan through the string in three characters at a time, But the code when I do it does not return the right 
number of 'bob' s. Please help, My code is down below.

```
# This function does not work correctly yet
# This function counts the number of bobs in a string
def bobs_counter():
    bob_count = 0
    s = 'waterbob'
    s_len = len(s)
    bob_counter = "bob"
    for q in range(0, s_len+1, 3):
        if bob_counter in s:
            bob_count += 1
        else:
            break
    print(bob_count)

bobs_counter()
```

Comment: You don't want to skip 3. What if the string is `bbob`? What is the expected output of `bobob`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `'waterbob'.count('bob')`.

```
'waterbob'.count('bob')    # 1
'bobwaterbob'.count('bob') # 2
```

Comment: Note that `str.count` only finds non-overlapping matches, e.g. `'bobob'.count('bob')` returns 1. It's not clear what OP wants.

Comment: @jpp Thanks for pointing it out! Should include that in a test case lol

Comment: Thank you jpp.I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

For non-overlapping, you can use @BubbleBubbleBubbleGut's suggestion.

Otherwise, you want to iterate through the string one step at a time, but comparing 3 characters each time.

### Example:

```
s = 'waterbobob'
match = 'bob'
match_count = 0
for i in range(0, len(s) + 1 - len(match)):
# this start the matching from the beginning to the last segment at the match length

    if s[i:i+len(match)] == match:
    # slice the string at the index + match length, giving you a segment of the exact length of the match to compare.
        match_count += 1

# match_count = 2
```

This will work with any `s` and `match` based on your initial definition.  This is of course, case sensitive.  If you want a non case sensitive version, consider converting everything to upper/lower case prior to comparing.